# Raise event in "recursive" class

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have an TreeView that is bound to an class like this:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsInitiallySelected, Mode=OneTime}" />
                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
            </Style>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxItemTemplate"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children.Values, Mode=OneTime}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Focusable="False" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='({0})'}"
                           Margin="5,2,2,5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <TreeView Grid.Column="0"
          x:Name="MyTree"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneTime}"      
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}"
          Margin="5"
          FontSize="14"
          Padding ="10"
          Width ="400"/>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Foo Root;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            ObjectDataProvider ODP = new ObjectDataProvider();
            ODP.MethodName = "CreateFoos";
            ODP.ObjectType = typeof(Foo);
            DataContext = ODP;

            InitializeComponent();
            Root = MyTree.Items[0] as Foo;
            Root.StatusChanged += Root_StatusChanged;
            MyTree.Focus();
        }

        void Root_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Changed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Foo.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event EventHandler StatusChanged;
        bool? _isChecked = false;
        public Dictionary<int, Foo> Children { get; set; }
        string _Name = "";
        Foo _parent;

        Foo(string MyName)
        {
            _Name = MyName;
            _isChecked = false;
            Children = new Dictionary<int, Foo>();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            foreach (Foo child in this.Children.Values)
            {
                child._parent = this;
                child.Initialize();
            }
        }

        public static List<Foo> CreateFoos()
        {
            Foo Base = new Foo("Test");

            Base.Children.Add(1, new Foo("Nr 1"));
            Base.Children.Add(2, new Foo("Nr 2"));
            Base.Children.Add(3, new Foo("Nr 3"));
            Base.Children[1].Children.Add(1, new Foo("Nr 1-1"));
            Base.Children[1].Children.Add(2, new Foo("Nr 1-2"));
            Base.Children[1].Children.Add(3, new Foo("Nr 1-3"));
            Base.Children[2].Children.Add(1, new Foo("Nr 2-1"));
            Base.Children[2].Children.Add(2, new Foo("Nr 2-2"));
            Base.Children[2].Children.Add(3, new Foo("Nr 2-3"));
            Base.Children[3].Children.Add(1, new Foo("Nr 3-1"));
            Base.Children[3].Children.Add(2, new Foo("Nr 3-2"));
            Base.Children[3].Children.Add(3, new Foo("Nr 3-3"));

            Base.Initialize();
            return new List<Foo> { Base };
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set { SetIsChecked(value, true, true); }
        }

        void SetIsChecked(bool? value, bool updateChildren, bool updateParent)
        {
            if (value == _isChecked)
                return;

            _isChecked = value;

            if (updateChildren && _isChecked.HasValue)
            {
                foreach (int Key in Children.Keys)
                {
                    Children[Key].SetIsChecked(_isChecked, true, false);
                }
            }

            if (updateParent && _parent != null)
            {
                _parent.VerifyCheckState();

            }

            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");

            EventHandler MyHandler = StatusChanged;
            if (null != MyHandler)
            {
                MyHandler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        void VerifyCheckState()
        {
            bool? state = null;
            bool CheckedFound = false;
            bool UncheckedFound = false;
            bool NullFound = false;
            foreach (int Key in Children.Keys)
            {
                if (Children[Key].IsChecked == true)
                {
                    CheckedFound = true;
                }
                else if (Children[Key].IsChecked == false)
                {
                    UncheckedFound = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    NullFound = true;
                }
            }
            if (CheckedFound && !UncheckedFound && !NullFound)
            {
                state = true;
            }
            else if (!CheckedFound && UncheckedFound && !NullFound)
            {
                state = false;
            }
            SetIsChecked(state, false, true);
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Result]

My Prolem now is, that the Event only fires when the status of the root node changes. But when I check/uncheck only Sub-Items the root-node not always changes, so I don't get this changes.
How do I have to change my code to get all changes, but also don't fire multiple events, because when I change one item multile other items (parent and children) can change also.

Comment: Where do you rise event? Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Your latest version of `Foo` doesn't even have a `_parent` field...

Comment: I completely rewrote my question, with 100% working code now. hope it's clearer now. Otherwise please ask.